# Feature tracking using Open CV ++

Tags: c++, opencv

i am trying to do feature tracking for a white bead(circular in shape) under the micro scope , I tried using a threshold , get contours and the use a kalman filter but the problem is that there is no major color difference between the bead and the noisy background, also the light from microscope is not uniform  so thresholding is not working good, i read about adaptive thresolding but i dont understand it really well. so any help or tips to track it would be highly appreciated

Comment: please add an image (or at least an url to it)

Comment: @berak here is the link of the image , https://imageshack.us/i/ipGhKopap